# What does this _=_=>_(_);_(_) mean?

Tags: javascript

I just came across this code

```
_=_=>_(_);_(_)
```

and it's written in javascript. I have no idea what this does. What does this smiley code mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not, in any way, related to what we do here.

Comment: it is valid javascript, but it blows the stack.

Comment: @el-teedee It actually is valid javascript

Comment: @mahhi.dasht This website is for programming Question and Answers. You should not post here unless you have an explicit, well defined question about a programming problem or concept.

Comment: All right, sorry. I only posted here because my friend told me that this is the best place to ask for help.

Comment: Btw, without a global, using a T-combinator `(_ => _(_))(_ => _(_))`

Comment: @NinaScholz What does "blows the stack" mean?

Comment: @JonasWilms That's even more confusing.

Comment: @maahi.dasht, it means it needs a bigger stack than exists. the original error text is: `Error: Out of stack space`. it is the result of vcalling the function again by handing over the same function without exit condition, which an elementary part of a recursive function.

Comment: @maahi.dasht in lay-person terms it just means that it completely occupies the computer. Imagine trying to do 50 things at once. This does a few different things depending on the system. Some handle it gracefully (I can only do X things at once) and some fail (crash)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Breaking down the syntax:

- `_=…` [implicitly declares a global variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) named `_` and assigns to it the result of the expression to the right. This would throw an error in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), unless the variable was already declared elsewhere.
- `_=>…` is a [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), also called [lambda expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#JavaScript), that accepts a parameter named `_` (which will shadow the name of the global variable) and returns the result of the expression to the right.
- `_(_)` calls the parameter `_` as though its a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions), passing in `_` as the first argument to that function. This works because JavaScript features [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), so they can be used as arguments to other functions or be returned from functions (this is not true in all languages).

So far, `_=_=>_(_);` creates a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) that accepts a function as a parameter and calls that second function with itself as an argument, then assigns it to a global variable named `_`.

- the final `_(_)` will call the global variable `_` with the same global variable, `_` as an argument.

The result would be a pretty quick [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow), since this is effectively a [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) without any escape condition. However, modern browsers will most likely gracefully break out of the infinite recursion by throwing an [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Too_much_recursion) rather than simply crashing.

```js
try {
    _=_=>_(_);_(_)
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.toString());
}
```

Comment: I don't really know what any of this means but I appreciate the effort you put into answering my question. Thank you. I guess I am not smart after all.

Comment: @maahi.dasht Don't be too hard on yourself. It's deliberately obfuscated to be difficult to understand and use fairly advanced concepts (lambda expressions and recursion take some effort to get your head around if you're new to them) and to be honest would be too difficult to explain all of those concepts fully in one answer. My main goal was to provide a jumping off point for you (or other readers) to do your own research.

Comment: So, `_=…` means that `_` is equal to `…`? Like for example, `2 + 3 = 5`? Also, in the article you linked they sometimes used `=` and other times they used `===`. What's the difference?

Comment: @maahi.dasht In mathematics `=` is a **statement of fact** regarding the relationship between two expressions, e.g. `2 + 3 = 5` means "*It is a fact that the expressions `2 + 3` and `5` represent identical values.*" In most programming languages `=` **assigns** a value to a variable, so `x = 2 + 3` means "*Evaluate `2 + 3` and store the result in variable `x`*". `===` is a **comparison** between two values, so `x === 2 + 3` means "*Evaluate `2 + 3` and check this result is the same as the value as what's stored variable `x`*" the result of the whole expression will be either `true` or `false`.